# xslt : renumber attribute value in context node and another node with same @ value

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <lev1>
        <source id="1"/>
        <target id="1"/>
    </lev1>
    <lev1>
        <source id="2"/>
        <sometag/>
        <lev2>
            <sometag/>
            <target id="2"/>
            <target id="4"/>
        </lev2>
        <source id="4"/>
        <sometag/>
        <source id="5"/>
        <lev2>
            <target id="6"/>
        </lev2>
    </lev1>
</root>
```

I want to renumber all the the `source/@id` values, and update any matching `target/@id` with the updated value. I would like all nodes to retain their original position, and I would like to generate a comment where a matching `target/@id` is not found.

This xslt was my starting point:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="kTarget" match="target" use="@id"/>


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="source">
<xsl:variable name="newId">
    <xsl:number from="/" level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
    <newsource>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$newId"/></xsl:attribute>
    </newsource>
    <xsl:call-template name="renumTarget">
        <xsl:with-param name="newId"><xsl:value-of select="$newId"/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="target"/>

<xsl:template name="renumTarget">
<xsl:param name="newId"/>
    <xsl:comment>new id : <xsl:value-of select="$newId"/> old id : <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:comment>
    <xsl:element name="newtarget">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$newId"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am able to pick out the old and new values...but not able to place the new node. This also does not identify areas where no matching @id exists.

Is there any way to create some kind of map that has oldVal->newVal kind of function in xslt?

thanks!

Comment: How would the result look like? I mean, what new values should be put into the empty places?

Comment: Suppose you have a target with id = 3, with no corresponding source. And suppose that renumbering the sources produces a source with id = 3. What should be the new id of the target with old id = 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want to generate the comment for a `source` respectively `newsource` without a corresponding `target` or a `target` without a `source`, the following generates both:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="kTarget" match="target" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="kSource" match="source" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source" mode="number">
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:variable name="newId">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <newsource id="{$newId}"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(key('kTarget', @id))">
            <xsl:comment>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('No target for old id ', @id, ' replaced by ', $newId)"/>
                </xsl:comment>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="target[key('kSource', @id)]">
        <xsl:variable name="changed-id">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kSource', @id)" mode="number"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <target id="{$changed-id}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="target[not(key('kSource', @id))]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('No source for target with id ', @id)"/>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input sample, I get the output

```
<root>
    <lev1>
        <newsource id="1"/>
        <target id="1"/>
    </lev1>
    <lev1>
        <newsource id="2"/>
        <sometag/>
        <lev2>
            <sometag/>
            <target id="2"/>
            <target id="3"/>
        </lev2>
        <newsource id="3"/>
        <sometag/>
        <newsource id="4"/><!--No target for old id 5 replaced by 4-->
        <lev2>
            <target id="6"/><!--No source for target with id 6-->
        </lev2>
    </lev1>
</root>
```

Comment: This can inadvertently assign an orphaned target to an arbitrary source.